# Is a Family Tree considered a Tree in computer science?

Tags: tree, computer-science

Is a **family tree** considered a **tree** in the context of Computer Science?

Comment: By definition, a child can only have one parent when using a `binary tree`.  That said, you can have multiple parents in many other hierarchies ..  Just not a tree.  Tree = single parent, multiple children.  View the [Concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  You could consider the ancestry of a single person to be a tree if you flip it upside down (so your parents are child nodes etc), except this is still not a tree because incest is a thing.  In both cases, however, it is a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: Well, it's got nothing to do with incest, per se.  Almost certainly my parents were related to each other somehow, even if it was eighth cousin twice removed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with your instructor: a family "tree" is not a tree as defined in math or computer science.  And @paddy, I believe there is no way to turn a general family "tree" into a tree even if you flip it upside down or whatever.  Just think of two parents with two children.  There's a cycle there, which you cannot get rid of, whatever you do (short of severing a branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a family tree is not a computer-scientific tree, for precisely the reason given by your professor.

A tree in computer science is a rooted (there's a distinguished node called the "root" which has no parents), directed (the edges point away from the root), connected (every node is connected to every other by a series of edges), acyclic (there is only one descending path from the root to any node) graph. The "acyclic" part implies that a node can have at most one parent, since otherwise we'd have two distinct paths from the root to the child node being considered (one passing through the father and the other through the mother).

Comment: I suppose the Yep goes to "Is his reasoning valid?" and not to "Is a Family Tree considered a Tree" (the title)

Comment: fixed this - thank you.